# ImportError: No module named opencv after installing python-opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I install opencv in python with running `$ sudo apt-get install python-opencv` and installed successfully. but when run this code

```
import opencv
import opencv.highgui
import time
import commands

def get_image():
    image = opencv.highgui.cvQueryFrame(camera)
    return opencv.adaptors.Ipl2PIL(image)

camera = opencv.highgui.cvCreateCameraCapture(-1)

while 1:
    image = get_image()
    image.thumbnail((32, 24, ))
    image = tuple(ord(i) for i in image.tostring())
    x = int((int((max(image) / 256.0) * 10) + 1) ** 0.5 / 3 * 10)
    cmd = ("sudo su -c 'echo " + str(x) +
        " > /sys/devices/virtual/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness'")
    status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
    assert status is 0
```

Got follow error

```
$ python bright.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bright.py", line 1, in <module>
    import opencv
ImportError: No module named opencv
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be importing is `cv2` not `opencv`, there is also no `highgui`. You might want to check out the [docs](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html#geometric-transformations)

Answer (score 1):

To install opencv for python you need the command
 `$ pip install opencv-python`

To import it so as to use in applications the import to call the package is
 
`import cv2`

Comment: Only the second part of this answer is relevant.