# Anaconda Jupyter Python2.7 "ImportError: No module named opencv"

Tags: python, opencv

I installed Anaconda and install Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda Navigator by following this tutorial: [Install Anaconda on Mac](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/), and then I set up a new environment called "Computer Vision" the programming language is Python 2.7, and then I installed libopencv, opencv, py-opencv. I want to test if OpenCV has been installed successfully, so I only write one line code

```
import opencv
```

And the error says

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-140d3f9c9adb> in <module>()
----> 1 import opencv

ImportError: No module named opencv
```

I do not understand why this happens, I am sure I launch Jupyter Notebook after I installed the OpenCV module. I also try to use Python3.7 but it still not work.

Thank you for taking care of this question.

Comment: Why are you using Python 2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named opencv after installing python-opencv in Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684661/importerror-no-module-named-opencv-after-installing-python-opencv-in-ubuntu-14)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opencv is imported via the line `import cv2`, instead of `import opencv`. This is true in both Python 2 and 3.